# making legend from a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, legend, cell-array

I think my problem may be quite common, but I did not find an answer. Maybe I am looking at this the wrong way!? How can I end up making a legend from this type of matrix:

X =

```
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 hard hm (50)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 hard hm (52)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 soft hm (56)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 soft hm (58)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 hard hm (50)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 hard hm (52)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 soft hm (56)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 soft hm (58)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [1000]    [25]    'm3 hard hex (53)'
[4.4200e+09]    [1000]    [25]    'm3 soft hex (59)'
```

where the length of the digits may vary, and the number of rows varies to...

```
class(X)
ans =
cell
```

When I write `legend(X)` matlab complaints. I have tried to solve the problem with sprintf using a loop like

```
sprintf('%d %d %d %s',X{ind,:})

ans =

4420012257 600 8 m2 hard hm (50)
```

where `ind` increments, but then I get the problem that the size may vary (some digits are longer)

The data that should be plotted is in two matricies. So I am looking at ending up with something like:

```
plot(t,y); legend(X)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
X = {[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 hard hm (50)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 hard hm (52)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 soft hm (56)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 soft hm (58)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 hard hm (50)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 hard hm (52)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm2 soft hm (56)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [ 600]    [ 8]    'm3 soft hm (58)' 
[4.4200e+09]    [1000]    [25]    'm3 hard hex (53)'
[4.4200e+09]    [1000]    [25]    'm3 soft hex (59)'}
```

You can use an implicit loop, specifying that the output of each iteration is stored in a cell, i.e. with `'UniformOutput', false` (equivalently `'un',0`):

```
X = arrayfun(@(ii) sprintf('%d %d %d %s',X{ii,:}), 1:size(X,1), 'un',0)';
```

The arrayfun is equivalent to:

```
nrows = size(X,1);
s = cell(nrows,1);
for ii = 1:nrows
    s{ii} = sprintf('%d %d %d %s',X{ii,:});
end
```